# Create Outlook email in HTML using Java application

Tags: java, outlook, html-email

I have a Java application that I have shared with my team that connects to a database to filter what materials are needed for a job. I have a Java button currently that I use to open a email in plain text format in outlook so the user can forward to other people. The formatting is very basic, so I would like to create email using HTML format but I cannot see how to do this.

I would not have other users SMTP details to automate the email. Is there any API out that can create a email (but not send) in Outlook and uses HTML formatting .

Can Java interact with another language to do this?

```
Desktop.getDesktop().mail(new URI( "mailto:email@gmail.com?subject="+subject+"&body="+body) );
```

This does what I need by creating a email that is independent of username or password, so I can give the Java application to anyone, but it's all plain text format, so it looks basic.

Comment: Yes, there are many Java libraries that can produce a HTML document. One example is Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify HTML body or attachments using the `mailto:` url. If you are running on the desktop, use Outlook Object Model: create an instance of the  `Outlook.Application` object, create new item using `Application.CreateItem(0)`, populate various `MailItem` properties (`To/CC/BCC`, Subject, `HTMLBody`, etc.), call `MailItem.Send`.